# TableCellRenderer, problema na exibição de cor na tabela

Tags: java, swing

É o seguinte, eu quero mudar a cor de letra uma especifica parte da minha tabela quando o pagamento do usuário está em dia para azul. Caso contrario, quero que mude para vermelho. Quero que só a coluna "situação" faça isso. Ou seja, Quando eu encontrar "ok" quero mudar para azul ou para vermelho quando encontrar "Pendente".

```
// Esse é meu Renderer
public class pagamentoTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
    // lista de objeto dos usuários
    private ArrayList<ModelUsuario> listaAluno;

    public pagamentoTableCellRenderer(ArrayList<ModelUsuario> situacao) {
        this.listaAluno = situacao;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        ModelUsuario situacao = listaAluno.get(row);

        if (situacao.getSituacao().equals("ok")) {

            setForeground(Color.blue);

        } else {
            setForeground(Color.red);
        }

        return this;
    }
}



public class ModeltabelaCarregar {


     public static  void main(String [] args) throws ParseException{
         new viewControleDePagamento().setVisible(true);;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse Caso você instancia um objeto DefaultTableCellRenderer ficando assim:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer colorRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            switch ((String) value) {
                case "Sim":
                    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);


                    break;
                case "Não":
                    setBackground(Color.WHITE);


                    break;
            }
            super.setValue(value);
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    };
```

O  parâmetro do método setCellRenderer requer um argumento TableCellRenderer:

```
suaTabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(colorRenderer);
```

Resultado é esse:

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

```
public class ColorirTabelaTramitacao extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
public static final float R = 0.9f;
public static final float G = 0.5f; 
public static final float B = 0.8f;

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
 super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
   //203,216,227
    //Color c = new Color(203,216,227);

    Color c = Color.WHITE;
    Object text = table.getValueAt(row, 3);
    Object text2 = table.getValueAt(row, 10);
    if (text != null && "LICENÇA EMITIDA".equals(text.toString())){
        // RGB
        c = new Color(126,195 ,255);
    }
    if(text != null && "DESARQUIVADO".equals(text.toString())){
        c = Color.GREEN;
    }
    if(text != null && "ARQUIVADO".equals(text.toString())){
        c = Color.RED;
    }
    if(text2 != null){
        c = Color.YELLOW;
    }

       setBackground(c);      


   if (isSelected){
          //setForeground(Color.BLUE);
          setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());    
  }



    return this;


}
```

}

Chama assim:

```
private void defineModelo() {
        tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) tblTramitacao.getModel();

        listModel = tblTramitacao.getSelectionModel();    

        tblTramitacao.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColorirTabelaTramitacao());
```

Vai ficar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: valeu cara, consegui resolver o problema! Mas teria com eu alterar a cor de apenas uma coluna?